# Docker Apple M1 : Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I a newbie so don't roast me too much, plase.
I downloaded and installed docker for m1 mac preview :

When I open Docker app it stays in phase : Docker is starting.
When I type in terminal any docker command it gives me response :  Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Any Ideas how to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4768

Comment: only restart your terminal

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved by,

Docker menu -> Troubleshoot -> Reset to factory defaults.

Caution:  Existing containers and images will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my M1 laptop.
Try to change your file sharing settings to osxfx (legacy)

"Settings" > "General" > "Choose file sharing implementation for your containers"
then choose "osxfs (Legacy)", apply and restart

Btw remember that this osxfs (Legacy) option is extremely slow